# Select visually first element while reordered by flex

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

Lets say I have a list with `display: flex` and inner elements reordered with `order: NNN;`.

So that first element in DOM can be N-th visually.

Is it possible using Javascript ( or some kind of CSS selector )select the element that visually comes first?

```html
<ul style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
<li style="order: 2;">1</li>
<li style="order: 12;">2</li>
<li style="order: 0;">select me please</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: better not to sort them by quering the ORDER css property.  Because some might not have one.

Comment: Please add a minimal html & css code related to this which others can use to review & test.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to give you the order of your elements, you can then use filters on your list to exclude invisible elements or anything you like.

jQuery btw has some helpful functions for such applications, would be a little cleaner with that.

```js
var nList = document.querySelectorAll('li');
var aList = Array.from(nList);
aList.sort(function(a,b) {
    var sAOrder = a.style.order ? parseInt(a.style.order) : 0;
    var sBOrder = b.style.order ? parseInt(b.style.order) : 0;
    return sAOrder-sBOrder;
});
console.log(aList);
```

```html
<ul style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
<li style="order: 2;">1</li>
<li style="order: 12;">2</li>
<li style="order: 0;">select me please</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar. In my case I was reordering Bootstrap tabs visually. This code works for me:

```
function showFirstTab() {
    var sortedTabs = $('#overviewTab li').sort(function (a, b) {
        aOrder = $(a).css('order');
        bOrder = $(b).css('order');
        var finalA = aOrder ? parseInt(aOrder) : 0;
        var finalB = bOrder ? parseInt(bOrder) : 0;
        return finalA - finalB;
    });
    sortedTabs.first().find('button').tab('show');
}
```

This code is using Bootstrap and jQuery. For some reason, the order values are always blank when I try to get them using plain JavaScript. Somehow, the jQuery version works.

Comment: This code works great without Bootstrap too, for those looking for a jQuery alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick.

- Calculate with js which is the `<li>` with the minimum order value.
- Added a class named `.first-element` to that element.

```js
let list = document
      .getElementById("list")
      .querySelectorAll('li');
const orders = [];

list.forEach((item, index) => {
      orders.push(item.style.order);
});

let minVal = Math.min(...orders);

list.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (minVal == item.style.order 
        && item.style.order !== "" ) {
         item.classList.add("first-element");
        }
});
```

```css
.first-element {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
<li style="order: 2;">1</li>
<li style="order: 12;">2</li>
<li style="order: 0;">select me please</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>
```